# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException When using Jsoup in Java

Tags: java, jsoup, web-crawler

I wrote code to crawl through and save images in a webpage. For some reason I am getting 
an error that i'm not sure how to fix.

I'm using a method to make sure that every image that I am indexing actually exists, so i'm not sure why this is happening.

here is my code:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.helper.Validate;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.*;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageReader;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;

public class jsoup {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    crawl("http://www.istockphoto.com/photo");
}

public static void crawl(String crawlurl) throws IOException{
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(crawlurl).get();
    getImgFromLinks(doc);
}

public static void getImgFromLinks(Document doc) throws IOException{
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
    //System.out.println(links);

    for(int i=0;i<links.size();i++){
        if(exists(links.get(i).attr("href"))){
            System.out.println("crawled: " + links.get(i).attr("href"));
            getImages(doc, links.get(i).attr("href"));
        }else{
            System.out.println("I couldnt crawl: " + links.get(i).attr("href"));
        }
    }
}

public static String smartUrl(String url, String src) {
    if(exists(src)){
        return(src);
    }else{
        return(url + src);
    }
}


public static void getImages(Document doc, String url) throws IOException{



      for(int i=0; i<doc.getElementsByTag("img").size();i++){
            Element image = doc.select("img").get(i);
            String imgsrc = image.attr("src");
            if(imgsrc.toLowerCase().contains("png") || imgsrc.toLowerCase().contains("jpg") || imgsrc.toLowerCase().contains("jpeg") || imgsrc.toLowerCase().contains("gif")){

            int slashIndex = smartUrl(url, imgsrc).lastIndexOf('/');
            String finalUrl = smartUrl(url, imgsrc).substring(slashIndex);

            URL imgurl = new URL(smartUrl(url, imgsrc));

            if(exists(imgurl.toString())){
            Image crawledimg = ImageIO.read(imgurl);


            ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) crawledimg, "gif",new File("/Users/Jonathan/Desktop/crawledimages" + finalUrl));


            System.out.println("I got an image from:" + url + " Image Name: " + finalUrl);
            }

        }
        }


}


public static boolean exists(String URLName) {
    try {
      HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);

    //HttpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
      HttpURLConnection con =
         (HttpURLConnection) new URL(URLName).openConnection();
      con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
      return (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
       return false;
    }
  }
}
```

here is the output:

```
crawled: http://www.istockphoto.com/
I got an image from:http://www.istockphoto.com/ Image Name: /blank.gif
I got an image from:http://www.istockphoto.com/ Image Name: /blank.gif
I got an image from:http://www.istockphoto.com/ Image Name: /blank.gif
I got an image from:http://www.istockphoto.com/ Image Name: /blank.gif
I got an image from:http://www.istockphoto.com/ Image Name: /blank.gif
I got an image from:http://www.istockphoto.com/ Image Name: /blank.gif
I got an image from:http://www.istockphoto.com/ Image Name: /blank.gif
I got an image from:http://www.istockphoto.com/ Image Name: /blank.gif
I got an image from:http://www.istockphoto.com/ Image Name: /facebook.png
I got an image from:http://www.istockphoto.com/ Image Name: /twitter.png
I got an image from:http://www.istockphoto.com/ Image Name: /blank.gif
I got an image from:http://www.istockphoto.com/ Image Name: /cartWhite.png
I couldnt crawl: #
I couldnt crawl: http://www.istockphoto.com/sign-in/aHR0cCUzQSUyRiUyRnd3dy5pc3RvY2twaG90by5jb20lMkZwaG90bw==
I couldnt crawl: http://www.istockphoto.com/join/aHR0cCUzQSUyRiUyRnd3dy5pc3RvY2twaG90by5jb20lMkZwaG90bw==
crawled: http://www.istockphoto.com/photo
I got an image from:http://www.istockphoto.com/photo Image Name: /blank.gif
I got an image from:http://www.istockphoto.com/photo Image Name: /blank.gif
I got an image from:http://www.istockphoto.com/photo Image Name: /blank.gif
I got an image from:http://www.istockphoto.com/photo Image Name: /blank.gif
I got an image from:http://www.istockphoto.com/photo Image Name: /blank.gif
I got an image from:http://www.istockphoto.com/photo Image Name: /blank.gif
I got an image from:http://www.istockphoto.com/photo Image Name: /blank.gif
I got an image from:http://www.istockphoto.com/photo Image Name: /blank.gif
I got an image from:http://www.istockphoto.com/photo Image Name: /facebook.png
I got an image from:http://www.istockphoto.com/photo Image Name: /twitter.png
I got an image from:http://www.istockphoto.com/photo Image Name: /blank.gif
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: im == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1457)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1527)
at jsoup.getImages(jsoup.java:68)
at jsoup.getImgFromLinks(jsoup.java:34)
at jsoup.crawl(jsoup.java:24)
at jsoup.main(jsoup.java:19)
```

The images are being saved until the error occurs.

Would anyone know how to fix this problem?

Also, for some reason the same images on a page are being saved multiple times.

Thank you for your time,

Jonathan Oren.

Comment: did you try running your code in a debugger to determine how you are getting a null value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `null` is being passed inside `ImageIO.write()`

smartURL function has a flaw which you will need to address. It is not creating an expected URL out of obtained image URLs from webpage.

For Example:
`/static/images/cartWhite.png` will be converted into `http://www.istockphoto.com/photo/static/images/cartWhite.png` by smartURL which is not an image but at the same time it is not an error page as well. So `crawledimg` refers to null giving rise to `IllegalArgumentException`.

A quick workaround for this would be to create `URL` with only `http://www.istockphoto.com` inside `getImages()`.

Images would be saved multiple times because each page have them. You could maintain a list of images to avoid this from happening.

I found another show stopper in your code, you will not  be able to retrieve any other image from the webpages you crawl. Images on the website doesn't end with `*.jpg` or `*.png` etc. So you will need to study the pattern of the image URLs on the website before starting.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I was able to fix the problem.